# PersistGate of redux-persist throwing 'Uncaught DOMException' when passing a react component inside loading parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-persist, domexception

I m using PersistGate, and getting error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.` as I pass a react component inside the loading prop but if I pass null , then working fine.
Below is the sample code piece :

```
<PersistGate 
      loading={<Loading />}
      onBeforeLift={onBeforeLift}
      persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
```

How to handle this loading props issue?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8834#issuecomment-1118083034) helps? It seems like there's a bug where you need to replace a Fragment (`<>`) with a `<div>` inside your `App`.

Comment: Yes I have seen that! The <App /> is not having any fragment inside.. seems like there is this fragment issue inside the PersistGate Loader component rendering because on passing loading={null} it is not throwing the issue